# Как протестировать ViewModel

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, junit, viewmodel

Есть такой класс:

```
public class EvolutionViewModel extends ViewModel implements EvolutionListener {
    private MutableLiveData<List<EvolutionListItem>> evolutionLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private List<EvolutionListItem> evolutionListItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public LiveData<List<EvolutionListItem>> getEvolutionData() {
        return evolutionLiveData;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Evolution evolution) {
        evolutionListItems.clear();
        addEvolutionToList(evolution, 0);
        evolutionLiveData.postValue(evolutionListItems);
    }

    private void addEvolutionToList(Evolution evolution, int level) {
        evolutionListItems.add(new EvolutionListItem(evolution.getName(), level));
        if ((evolution == null) || (evolution.getEvolution() == null) || (evolution.getEvolution().size() == 0)) {
            return;
        }
        level++;
        for (Evolution childEvolution : evolution.getEvolution()) {
            addEvolutionToList(childEvolution, level);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure() {
        evolutionLiveData.postValue(new ArrayList<EvolutionListItem>());
    }
}
```

Вот мой тест:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class EvolutionViewModelTest {
@Rule
public TestRule rule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();

private EvolutionViewModel evolutionViewModel;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    evolutionViewModel = new EvolutionViewModel();
}

@Test
public void onEvolutionTest() {
    Evolution evolutionRoot = new Evolution();
    evolutionRoot.setName("nameRoot");
    List<Evolution> evolutions = new ArrayList<>();
    Evolution evolutionChild = new Evolution();
    evolutionChild.setName("evolutionChild");
    evolutions.add(evolutionChild);
    evolutionRoot.setEvolution(evolutions);

    evolutionViewModel = new EvolutionViewModel();
    evolutionViewModel.onSuccess(evolutionRoot);

    assertEquals(2, evolutionViewModel.getEvolutionData().getValue().size());
    }
}
```

Получаю `NullPointerException` на `assertEquals()`. Подскажите, что не так?
Причем когда прошла с debug, то тест прошел, а без него нет. Похоже, что просто надо как-то притормозить, пока метод сработает.